# Nodejs Http Proxy Server Gives Socket Hang up Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I have created a containerized proxy server (say worker server) that listens on port 5000. I ran the container with `--network=host` option so that it may access the ports on host machine without needing the `-p` flag.The server has an endpoint `get-buttons`. The endpoint executes a shell script and then forwards the request to port 6000 of host machine with the same endpoint. I have used `http-proxy` of nodejs. The code is given below:

```
const express = require('express');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const { exec, execSync } = require('child_process');

const app = express();
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

app.get('/get-buttons', (req, res) => {
  // Execute a shell script
  exec(`sh hello_world.sh ${req.query.abc}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error starting engine: ${error}`);
      res.status(500).send('Error executing shell script');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Shell script executed successfully');
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:6000/get-buttons' }, function (error) {
      console.log("Proxy Error ", error)
    });
  });
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Worker server is running on port 5000');
});
```

I get the following error every time

```
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:639:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:499:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1333:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET
```

It may be noted that, if I run `curl localhost:6000/get-buttons` from inside the container, it gives me a response. I am confused, if the curl command works,why the nodejs proxy giving me a socker hang up error.

Answer (score 0):

http-proxy does not replace the path you are calling, only the host (but with the target path as well). The server on `:6000` is receiving a request for /get-buttons/get-buttons.

To reproduce:

- Use your exact code in a simple container with network host flag.
- Start a new netcat listener with `nc -ltp 6000` on the host
- Run `curl localhost:5000/get-buttons`
- Confirm output from `nc`:

```
GET /get-buttons/get-buttons HTTP/1.1
accept: */*
user-agent: curl/7.81.0
host: localhost:5000
connection: close
```

You can change the target to the following to get the desired result:

```
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:6000'}
```

The above code yields the below on the target:

```
:: nc -ltp 6000
GET /get-buttons HTTP/1.1
accept: */*
user-agent: curl/7.81.0
host: localhost:5000
connection: close
```

#### Update:

If you are really just wanting to "call some other server", not "proxy the request", you can have a look at [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), they might be a better fit for your use-case with less surprises

#### Update 2:

Removed req.url rewrite based on the update question

Comment: Hi, I am sorry. I was actually trying to forward requests to the same endpoint `get-buttons`. Please see the updated question.

Comment: It's really the same answer, less the rewrite, I've updated as well.

Comment: Hi, I set the target as `http://127.0.0.1:6000` and still getting the error

Comment: If you run `nc -ltp 6000` on the host (I am assuming it is linux) instead of the normal server, and you test, does it show any output, and if so, what is it? Or are there logs in the current server running on :6000 indicating that it did receive the request?